# How to secure UniData session using UniObjects for .net

Tags: c#, .net, security, ssl, unidata

How do you secure a UniData session using UniObjects for .net?

The [documentation](http://dl.getdropbox.com/u/1563210/uonet.pdf) is severely lacking. The [UniObjects for Java documentation](http://dl.getdropbox.com/u/1563210/Java.pdf) has a whole chapter on SSL.

## EDIT

The UniObjects .net documentation says this about the UniSession.EncryptionType property:

> public int EncryptionType {get; set}
>
> This property gets or sets the default encryption type for the session.
>
> int is the token number for the encryption type, as follows:
>
> 0 - UniObjectsTokens.NO_ENCRYPT - No encryption. This is the default value.
>
> 1 - UniObjectsTokens.UV_ENCRYPT - Encrypt all data using internal database encryption.
>
> If you set UV_ENCRYPT for a session, all data transferred between client and server is encrypted.

If I set my UniSession object's EncryptionType property to 1 (UniObjectsTokens.UV_ENCRYPT), when I call my UniCommand's Execute method, I get an IBMU2.UODOTNET.UniRPCPacketException that says

> "[IBM U2][UODOTNET - UNIRPC][ErrorCode=81004] An argument was requested from the RPC that was of an invalid type"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A very special person found this for me:

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=14266821

I will report my findings. More input is welcome.

## EDIT

After some research, I found that SSL with UniObjects will only work with Unidata 7.2. My school has 7.1 and we aren't upgrading just yet. But a great developer at another school had a work around. We secured our Uniobjects communication using SSH Port Forwarding. Beautiful. On the computer that runs the uniobjects code, we used srvany.exe and an ssh client to create a windows service. In the ssh client we forward traffic from localhost:uniobjects_port to unidata_server:22.

Answer (score 0):

Look at Chapter 4 in the [UniData Security Features [pdf]](http://www.rocketsoftware.com/u2/epubs/pdf/29920960.pdf) document for SSL support.  It looks like you can modify your UniObjects connection string to specify that you want a secure connection:

> In previous versions, the ConnectionString property was used only to specify the server process to be used for the session. It now provides a second set of parameters to specify a secure connection.

Comment: How does this relate to UniObjects for .NET?

Comment: The section I'm quoting is specifically related to UniObjects.

Comment: From the document: "The UniObjects session object properties include a ConnectionString property."  I checked the session object in UniObjects for .NET. There is no such property. The information that you are referencing either has to do with UniObjects (VB) or UniObjects for Java.